# systemd-nspawn: how to select root partition if ambiguous on image?

Tags: systemd-nspawn

I have pendrive which (as `/dev/sdb`) after opening LUKS device on `dev/sdb4` looks

```
NAME                               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sdb                                  8:16   1 235.8G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                               8:17   1     2M  0 part  
├─sdb2                               8:18   1   128M  0 part  
├─sdb3                               8:19   1   256M  0 part  
└─sdb4                               8:20   1 235.4G  0 part  
  └─rageCrypt                      253:6    0 235.4G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgRageP256G-lvRageRootDebian 253:7    0    60G  0 lvm   
    ├─vgRageP256G-lvRageRootOther  253:8    0    20G  0 lvm   
    └─vgRageP256G-lvRageHome       253:9    0 155.4G  0 lvm
```

I would like to boot it using `systemd-nspawn`. I tried

```
systemd-nspawn -b --image /dev/sdb
```

but get `/dev/sdb: Multiple suitable root partitions found in image.` and did not found in manual and network any suggestion how to tell systemd-nspawn to look for root partition on sdb4.